# Chinese citizen with Green Card transit in Incheon airport flying from Beijing to Seattle - do I need a visa?

Tags: transit, chinese-citizens

I'm flying back from Beijing to Seattle with layover at Incheon Airport for 6 hours. No plan to get out of the airport. Do I need to have a visa for the transit? The first leg is operated by Air China and the second one by Asiana Airlines. They were issued by the travel agent as one route ticket. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/US-USA-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm#), it looks like you are ok to travel through ICN without a visa. See below and the link for more info.

[image: ICN Chinese Citizen]